# template template function parameter

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, template-templates

For the life of me, I can't get this simple piece of arcane template magic to work:

```
template<typename T, int a, int b>
int f(T v){
  return v*a-b; // just do something for example
}

template<typename T, int a, int b, template<typename,int,int> class func>
class C{
  int f(){
    return func<T,a,b>(3);
  }
};

int main(){
  C<float,3,2, f> c;
}
```

Is this possible to do without involving functors?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my compiler crashed while executing this code.

Comment: @nijansen isn't MSVS2010 stable??

Comment: @Saksham No, no, no. Just no.

Comment: don't be fooled, it's stable enough. As usual the problem lies in the code

Comment: @nijansen just simplifying some unit tests for legacy code. I can't change to functors as that would be too much work in the codebase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

f is supposed to be a class - you have a function.

See below:

```
// Class acts like a function - also known as functor.
template<typename T, int a, int b>
class f
{
  int operator()(T v)
  {
    return v*a-b; // just do something for example
  }
};

template<typename T, int a, int b, template<typename,int,int> class func>
class C
{
  int f()
  {
    return func<T,a,b>(3);
  }
};

int main()
{
  C<float,3,2, f> c;
}
```

... And the adapted version if you need to port legacy code (Adapts the function to a class template):

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename T, int a, int b>
int f(T v)
{
  std::cout << "Called" << std::endl;
  return v*a-b; // just do something for example
}

template<typename T, int a, int b, template<typename,int,int> class func>
struct C
{
  int f()
  {
    return func<T,a,b>(3);
  }
};

template <class T, int a, int b>
struct FuncAdapt
{
  T x_;
  template <class U>
  FuncAdapt( U x )
  : x_( x )
  {}
  operator int() const
  {
    return f<T,a,b>( x_ );
  }
};

int main()
{
  C<float,3,2, FuncAdapt > c;
  c.f();
}
```

Comment: congratulations for your first points

Comment: Thanks. I see I need a reputation to upvote someone... Hence I answered a question.

Comment: Didn't the OP wanted it without using functors? (quote: "Is this possible to do without involving functors?")

Comment: I specifically stated I did not want to use a functor. I can't change the signature or calling syntax of `f`.

Comment: How about write an adapter that adapts f to the given functor.

Comment: Apologies for the code that did not compile. I never called f in my test. It compiles now. The Adapter needs to have a constructor to accept T and a conversion operator for the return value.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it was the closest to what I wanted. However do I believe there is a possibility that the adapter class could be made more generic to simplify syntax. I just don't have time to look into it :)

Answer (score 7):

You can solve it through a little trickery:

```
template<typename T, int a, int b>
int f(T v){
  return v*a-b; // just do something for example
}

template<typename T, int, int>
using func_t = int (*)(T);

template<typename T, int a, int b, func_t<T, a, b> func>
class C{
  int f(){
    return func(3);
  }
};

C<float,3,2, f<float, 3, 2>> c;
```

First you need a type-alias for the function (`func_t` above), and you unfortunately need to duplicate the template arguments in the declaration of `c`.

Comment: ...in C++11, if your compiler supports template aliases. MSVC 2013 *still* doesn't

Comment: I wanted to avoid the duplication of the template arguments, this is supposed to save me from typing/copypaste a lot in my unit tests. Appart from that, this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. Even the syntax:

```
template <typename T, int a, int b, template <typename, int, int> class func>
                                                                  ^^^^^
```

shows that an argument for a template template parameter must be a class template.

Comment: Yes I know, I was looking for some trickery just to avoid changing my production code to make unit testing code more neat.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your compiler is complaining is that you're passing a function (`f`) as a class to the last template parameter for class `C`.

Since you cannot pass a function as a template parameter, you should use function pointers or functors. And functors are definitely the cleaner way to do this.

So, although it's possible to achieve what you want without using functors, you really shouldn't try to.

If you want to use function pointers you will be looking at something like this:

```
template<typename T, int a, int b, int (*func)(T)>
class C{
    int f(){
        return (*func)(3);
    }
};

int main(){
    C< float,3,2,&f<float,3,2> > c;
}
```

In that case I don't think you would be able to eliminate the code duplication in the declaration of `c`, but I might be wrong.